# geocoding in Python using googlemaps

Tags: python, file, csv, geocode

I have several problems with these codes that I've just written. Code is below:-

```
from googlemaps import GoogleMaps
import urllib, json
import csv

def geocode(addr):
url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=%s&sensor=false" %    (urllib.quote(addr.replace(' ', '+')))
data = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
info = json.loads(data).get("results")[0].get("geometry").get("location")

return info

with open('addtest.csv', 'rb') as f:
reader = csv.reader(f)
for row in reader:
    row_count = sum(1 for row in reader)
    for i in range(0, row_count):
        r = geocode(row[i])
        print ("%s %s" % (r['lat'], r['lng']))
        csv_out = open('addtest_c.csv', 'wb')
        mywriter = csv.writer(csv_out)
        mywriter.writerows("%s %s" % (r['lat'], r['lng']))
```

What am I trying to do is to get the addresses (row by row), geocode them, and write the coordinates in another csv file. If the coordinate for the place is not found, then the script will write 'not found' instead in the output csv file.

I tried the script above but the output becomes this:-

```
1,.,8,4,9,4,4,2, ,1,0,2,.,9,2,8,8,3,4,1
```

I have 12 rows in my test file (named addtest.csv), example below:-

```
Kg Sg Nibong,Lubuk,Semerah,Parit Sulong,Batu Pahat,Johor
Kg Parit Bentong,Spg Kiri,Sri Medan,Parit Sulong,Batu Pahat,Johor
Ldg B-1, Yong Peng,Tg Semberong,Yong Peng,Ayer Hitam,Batu Pahat,Johor
Kg Sri Belahan,Sg Kluang,Rengit,Batu Pahat,Batu Pahat,Johor
Parit Besar,Bagan,Semerah,Parit Sulong,Batu Pahat,Johor
Spg Tiga Bagan,Bagan,Semerah,Parit Sulong,Batu Pahat,Johor
Parit Besar,Bagan,Semerah,Parit Sulong,Batu Pahat,Johor
Parit Selulon,Linau,Parit Yaani,Sri Gading,Batu Pahat,Johor
Parit Khalil,Sri Gading,Semarang,Ayer Hitam,Batu Pahat,Johor
Kg Parit Dalam,Sri Medan,Sri Medan,Parit Sulong,Batu Pahat,Johor
Kg Parit Jatuh,Tg Semberong,Yong Peng,Ayer Hitam,Batu Pahat,Johor
Parit Orang Kaya,Bagan,Semerah,Parit Sulong,Batu Pahat,Johor
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. If you need more information please comment. I am using Python 2.7.8 on Windows.